# How can I improve this mysql pivot query?

Tags: mysql, drupal-7, drupal-webform

I'm working with a Drupal site and I need to pull a report of webform submissions.

The Table structure is such:

```
webform_submissions
- sid
- nid
- serial
- uid
- is_draft
- submitted
- remote_addr

webform_submitted_data
- nid
- sid
- cid
- no
- data
```

So when a submission is made something like this goes into each table:
webform_submissions

```
sid: 1, nid:100, serial: 1, uid: 0, is_draft: 0, submitted: [timestamp], remote_addr: 0.0.0.0
```

webform_submitted_data

```
nid: 100, sid: 1, cid: 1, no: 0, data: John
nid: 100, sid: 1, cid: 2, no: 0, data: Doe
```

There is also another table that maps the cid to the form field name but I'm not worried about that.

for every row in the webform_submissions table that matches a nid I need a row with all of the corresponding data in the webform_submitted_data.

result_set
    nid: 100, cid_1: John, cid_2: Doe

the actual form data I need has about 30 fields.

This is the best query I have been able to come up with:

```
SELECT ws.nid, wd_c2.data, wd_c3.data
FROM    webform_submissions ws, 
        webform_submitted_data wd_c2,
        webform_submitted_data wd_c3
WHERE   ws.nid = 168
AND     ws.sid = wd_c3.sid
AND     wd_c3.cid = 3
AND     ws.sid = wd_c2.sid
AND     wd_c2.cid = 2;
```

That query takes nearly 20 seconds on my local mysql to pull 8 records.  I can only assume my approach is not a good one.  What is a better way to get all of the rows related to a submission from the webform_submitted_data table into a single row of columns in my result set.

FULL QUERY updated with Joins (returns empty set).

```
SELECT ws.nid, 
wd_c2.data  as 'First Name', 
wd_c3.data  as 'Last Name', 
wd_c4.data  as 'Email Address', 
wd_c5.data  as 'Primary Phone', 
wd_c6.data  as 'Secondary Phone', 
wd_c7.data  as 'Address', 
wd_c8.data  as 'City', 
wd_c9.data  as 'State', 
wd_c10.data as 'Zip Code', 
wd_c11.data as 'Cf', 
wd_c12.data as 'AR', 
wd_c13.data as 'G', 
wd_c14.data as 'PE', 
wd_c15.data as 'PD', 
wd_c16.data as 'AN', 
wd_c17.data as 'V', 
wd_c18.data as 'S', 
wd_c19.data as 'V2', 
wd_c20.data as 'S', 
wd_c21.data as 'Si', 
wd_c22.data as 'D', 
wd_c23.data as 'M', 
wd_c24.data as 'L', 
wd_c25.data as 'V', 
wd_c26.data as 'C', 
wd_c27.data as 'O', 
wd_c28.data as 'M', 
wd_c29.data as 'P', 
wd_c30.data as 'C', 
wd_c31.data as 'C', 
wd_c32.data as 'C', 
wd_c33.data as 'E', 
wd_c34.data as 'Ey', 
wd_c41.data as 'TD', 
wd_c42.data as 'RN', 
wd_c43.data as 'TP', 
wd_c45.data as 'LM', 
wd_c47.data as 'PIp', 
wd_c48.data as 'wd', 
wd_c49.data as 'Cr', 
wd_c50.data as 'N', 
wd_c51.data as 'A'

FROM webform_submissions ws 
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c2    on ws.sid = wd_c2.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c3    on ws.sid = wd_c3.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c4    on ws.sid = wd_c4.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c5    on ws.sid = wd_c5.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c6    on ws.sid = wd_c6.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c7    on ws.sid = wd_c7.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c8    on ws.sid = wd_c8.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c9    on ws.sid = wd_c9.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c10   on ws.sid = wd_c10.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c11   on ws.sid = wd_c11.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c12   on ws.sid = wd_c12.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c13   on ws.sid = wd_c13.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c14   on ws.sid = wd_c14.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c15   on ws.sid = wd_c15.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c16   on ws.sid = wd_c16.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c17   on ws.sid = wd_c17.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c18   on ws.sid = wd_c18.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c19   on ws.sid = wd_c19.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c20   on ws.sid = wd_c20.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c21   on ws.sid = wd_c21.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c22   on ws.sid = wd_c22.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c23   on ws.sid = wd_c23.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c24   on ws.sid = wd_c24.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c25   on ws.sid = wd_c25.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c26   on ws.sid = wd_c26.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c27   on ws.sid = wd_c27.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c28   on ws.sid = wd_c28.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c29   on ws.sid = wd_c29.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c30   on ws.sid = wd_c30.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c31   on ws.sid = wd_c31.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c32   on ws.sid = wd_c32.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c33   on ws.sid = wd_c33.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c34   on ws.sid = wd_c34.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c41   on ws.sid = wd_c41.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c42   on ws.sid = wd_c42.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c43   on ws.sid = wd_c43.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c45   on ws.sid = wd_c45.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c47   on ws.sid = wd_c47.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c48   on ws.sid = wd_c48.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c49   on ws.sid = wd_c49.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c50   on ws.sid = wd_c50.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c51   on ws.sid = wd_c51.sid
INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c52   on ws.sid = wd_c52.sid

WHERE   ws.nid = 16818

AND     wd_c2.cid = 2
AND     wd_c3.cid = 3
AND     wd_c4.cid = 4
AND     wd_c5.cid = 5
AND     wd_c6.cid = 6
AND     wd_c7.cid = 7
AND     wd_c8.cid = 8
AND     wd_c9.cid = 9
AND     wd_c10.cid =    10
AND     wd_c11.cid =    11
AND     wd_c12.cid =    12
AND     wd_c13.cid =    13
AND     wd_c14.cid =    14
AND     wd_c15.cid =    15
AND     wd_c16.cid =    16
AND     wd_c17.cid =    17
AND     wd_c18.cid =    18
AND     wd_c19.cid =    19
AND     wd_c20.cid =    20
AND     wd_c21.cid =    21
AND     wd_c22.cid =    22
AND     wd_c23.cid =    23
AND     wd_c24.cid =    24
AND     wd_c25.cid =    25
AND     wd_c26.cid =    26
AND     wd_c27.cid =    27
AND     wd_c28.cid =    28
AND     wd_c29.cid =    29
AND     wd_c30.cid =    30
AND     wd_c31.cid =    31
AND     wd_c32.cid =    32
AND     wd_c33.cid =    33
AND     wd_c34.cid =    34
AND     wd_c41.cid =    41
AND     wd_c42.cid =    42
AND     wd_c43.cid =    43
AND     wd_c45.cid =    45
AND     wd_c47.cid =    47
AND     wd_c48.cid =    48
AND     wd_c49.cid =    49
AND     wd_c50.cid =    50
AND     wd_c51.cid =    51
AND     wd_c52.cid =    52
LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure you have proper index on webform_submissions(nid, sid), webform_submitted_data(sid, cid) (and for a better readiing use join notation instead of where/and clause )

```
    SELECT ws.nid, wd_c2.data, wd_c3.data
    FROM        webform_submissions ws   
    INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c2  on ws.sid = wd_c2.sid
    INNER JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c3  on ws.sid = wd_c3.sid
    WHERE   ws.nid = 168
    AND     wd_c3.cid = 3
    AND     wd_c2.cid = 2;
```

eg for the index

```
 CREATE INDEX ws_id on  webform_submissions(nid, sid)
```

try using left join (so if a value don't match the query work however)

```
SELECT ws.nid, 
wd_c2.data  as 'First Name', 
wd_c3.data  as 'Last Name', 
wd_c4.data  as 'Email Address', 
wd_c5.data  as 'Primary Phone', 
wd_c6.data  as 'Secondary Phone', 
wd_c7.data  as 'Address', 
wd_c8.data  as 'City', 
wd_c9.data  as 'State', 
wd_c10.data as 'Zip Code', 
wd_c11.data as 'Cf', 
wd_c12.data as 'AR', 
wd_c13.data as 'G', 
wd_c14.data as 'PE', 
wd_c15.data as 'PD', 
wd_c16.data as 'AN', 
wd_c17.data as 'V', 
wd_c18.data as 'S', 
wd_c19.data as 'V2', 
wd_c20.data as 'S', 
wd_c21.data as 'Si', 
wd_c22.data as 'D', 
wd_c23.data as 'M', 
wd_c24.data as 'L', 
wd_c25.data as 'V', 
wd_c26.data as 'C', 
wd_c27.data as 'O', 
wd_c28.data as 'M', 
wd_c29.data as 'P', 
wd_c30.data as 'C', 
wd_c31.data as 'C', 
wd_c32.data as 'C', 
wd_c33.data as 'E', 
wd_c34.data as 'Ey', 
wd_c41.data as 'TD', 
wd_c42.data as 'RN', 
wd_c43.data as 'TP', 
wd_c45.data as 'LM', 
wd_c47.data as 'PIp', 
wd_c48.data as 'wd', 
wd_c49.data as 'Cr', 
wd_c50.data as 'N', 
wd_c51.data as 'A'

FROM webform_submissions ws 
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c2    on ws.sid = wd_c2.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c3    on ws.sid = wd_c3.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c4    on ws.sid = wd_c4.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c5    on ws.sid = wd_c5.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c6    on ws.sid = wd_c6.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c7    on ws.sid = wd_c7.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c8    on ws.sid = wd_c8.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c9    on ws.sid = wd_c9.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c10   on ws.sid = wd_c10.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c11   on ws.sid = wd_c11.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c12   on ws.sid = wd_c12.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c13   on ws.sid = wd_c13.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c14   on ws.sid = wd_c14.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c15   on ws.sid = wd_c15.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c16   on ws.sid = wd_c16.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c17   on ws.sid = wd_c17.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c18   on ws.sid = wd_c18.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c19   on ws.sid = wd_c19.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c20   on ws.sid = wd_c20.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c21   on ws.sid = wd_c21.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c22   on ws.sid = wd_c22.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c23   on ws.sid = wd_c23.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c24   on ws.sid = wd_c24.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c25   on ws.sid = wd_c25.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c26   on ws.sid = wd_c26.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c27   on ws.sid = wd_c27.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c28   on ws.sid = wd_c28.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c29   on ws.sid = wd_c29.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c30   on ws.sid = wd_c30.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c31   on ws.sid = wd_c31.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c32   on ws.sid = wd_c32.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c33   on ws.sid = wd_c33.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c34   on ws.sid = wd_c34.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c41   on ws.sid = wd_c41.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c42   on ws.sid = wd_c42.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c43   on ws.sid = wd_c43.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c45   on ws.sid = wd_c45.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c47   on ws.sid = wd_c47.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c48   on ws.sid = wd_c48.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c49   on ws.sid = wd_c49.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c50   on ws.sid = wd_c50.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c51   on ws.sid = wd_c51.sid
LEFT JOIN  webform_submitted_data wd_c52   on ws.sid = wd_c52.sid

WHERE   ws.nid = 16818

AND     wd_c2.cid = 2
AND     wd_c3.cid = 3
AND     wd_c4.cid = 4
AND     wd_c5.cid = 5
AND     wd_c6.cid = 6
AND     wd_c7.cid = 7
AND     wd_c8.cid = 8
AND     wd_c9.cid = 9
AND     wd_c10.cid =    10
AND     wd_c11.cid =    11
AND     wd_c12.cid =    12
AND     wd_c13.cid =    13
AND     wd_c14.cid =    14
AND     wd_c15.cid =    15
AND     wd_c16.cid =    16
AND     wd_c17.cid =    17
AND     wd_c18.cid =    18
AND     wd_c19.cid =    19
AND     wd_c20.cid =    20
AND     wd_c21.cid =    21
AND     wd_c22.cid =    22
AND     wd_c23.cid =    23
AND     wd_c24.cid =    24
AND     wd_c25.cid =    25
AND     wd_c26.cid =    26
AND     wd_c27.cid =    27
AND     wd_c28.cid =    28
AND     wd_c29.cid =    29
AND     wd_c30.cid =    30
AND     wd_c31.cid =    31
AND     wd_c32.cid =    32
AND     wd_c33.cid =    33
AND     wd_c34.cid =    34
AND     wd_c41.cid =    41
AND     wd_c42.cid =    42
AND     wd_c43.cid =    43
AND     wd_c45.cid =    45
AND     wd_c47.cid =    47
AND     wd_c48.cid =    48
AND     wd_c49.cid =    49
AND     wd_c50.cid =    50
AND     wd_c51.cid =    51
AND     wd_c52.cid =    52
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: So this query worked for 2 data columns but when I added all 30 it returns an empty set.

Comment: are you really sure that all your wd_c*.cid match with the related value? .. try using left join

Comment: I think this is the correct approach I have some more data issues to resolve because some sid/cid combinations return multiple rows.  But your example and help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @JonDiamond   thanks .. if you thinks this is the right answer .. please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125449/discussion-between-jon-diamond-and-scaisedge).

Answer (score 1):

You're doing an inner join, which requires that records be present on BOTH sides of ALL the joins. If any of those fields don't exist, then the whole record is ignored. You probably want a `left join` instead.

As for efficiency, basic rule of thumb for databases: Any field used in a "decision context", e.g. a `where` or `join`, should have an index on it.